# JSONObject.getString() is aways null

Tags: null, json, getstring

I'm writing a Projekt with Android Studio, where I need to parse a JSON-String. But if i try to parse it with JSONObjects, I get always null, this is my code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class JSONTest {

    public void test() {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{\"test\":\"bla\"}");
        System.out.println(object.getString("test"));
    }
}
```

and it returns always null.
I tried many difrent ways to solve this, but it never worked.
Is there any issue with Android Studio?

Comment: I have tried this on my project and is working ok                             JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{\"test\":\"bla\"}");
                            String s = object.getString("test"); sorry that i can't help

Comment: this are my imports import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: And Android Studio always tells me to use a try / catch try {

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }

Answer (score 0):

The following code works like a charm in Android Studio. The snippet has to be surrounded in a try catch block.

```
JSONObject object = null;

    try {
        object = new JSONObject("{\"test\":\"bla\"}");
        System.out.println(object.getString("test"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

// Output: 11-09 22:21:21.586 32743-32743/in.example I/System.out: bla
```